# How can I handle flags without parameters in bash without using getopts?

Tags: bash, flags

I am perfectly able to manage flags with parameters with this syntax:

```
while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
do
key="$1"

case $key in

-c)
ARGUMENT_OF_C_FLAG="$2"
shift # past argument
;; 
*) 
;;
esac
done
```

How can I use the same syntax (without `getopts`) to manaage flags without parameters?

I try to use the same syntax for flags without parameter but it didn't work. For instance for a flag c with parameter and a flag d without parameters, I used without success

```
while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
do
key="$1"
case $key in

-c)
ARGUMENT_OF_C_FLAG="$2"
shift # past argument
;; 
-d)
IS_d_FLAG_SET=1
;;
*) 
;;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to test with `ge` not `gt` or you're not entering the loop when there's only one switch without option.

Then you have to `shift` at each loop or you'll have infinite loop

The `shift` you were performing when there's an argument got past the option, not the argument, and the error was compensated by `gt` instead of `ge` in the while.

```
while [[ $# -ge 1 ]]
do
key="$1"
case $key in

-c)
ARGUMENT_OF_C_FLAG="$2"
shift # past switch, argument will be skipped by the shift below
;; 
-d)
IS_d_FLAG_SET=1
;;
*)
echo "unexpected option $key"
;;
esac
shift
done

echo $ARGUMENT_OF_C_FLAG
echo $IS_d_FLAG_SET
```

Comment: I replaced gt by ge and it is now working. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget the extra shift or you'll be stuck if there is more than 1 switch without option. I have edited my post.